# Parse JSON file using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

I have a link which contains the a json file. I mean if I launch that link in chrome a file is downloaded on my computer which is of .json extension.
say the link is `www.foffa.com/sampleList.json`
I am new to AFNetworking and not sure how to parse this json, with or without having to write this file down to the disk.

My code looks like below and I am pretty sure that I have to use streams and all for this but I am not sure how. As of now I get an error `"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain"`
I guess it expects the content type to be  `"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";`

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/octet-stream"];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"Data retrived");       
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
```

Comment: Content type of your response seems to be set to `text/plain`. Either you need to get it changed from your server side to the one you are accepting or you need to add `text/plain` as acceptable content types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the second line in this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

to this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Note you are using the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` response serialised.

**Update**

Updating my answer from info in the below comments, it appears you actually want to download a JSON file from a  server and then parse it as opposed to parsing JSON directly from the HTTP response:

In order to do that change the content type to `text/plain` and with the downloaded `file/data` parse either as a `String` or a `JSON` object like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:nil];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =
    [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/octet-stream", @"text/plain", nil];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSError *error;
  id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&error];
  if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);
  }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                      message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alertView show];
}];
```

Comment: Yes... I think the idea here is to download the file first and then parse it. May be afnetworking can't do it on the fly

Comment: I couldn't get that url to work when testing (404), so I tested with `http://ip.jsontest.com` and the above works but you need to change the expected type to `application/json` not `application/octet-stream` I would test with that `http://ip.jsontest.com` or some other valid `JSON` response vs the one you had as it seems the `URL` is forcing a download of that file.

Comment: can you give this in objective-c please.. I m not familiar with swift.

Comment: I was practically doing the same thing except for the @"text/plain" value in acceptable content types.. why do you thing it used to fail..?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava `AFNetworking` is pretty particular in the response it expects. You were saying that you are expecting a `application/octet-stream` response but in fact were getting a `text/plain` response so it was throwing an error saying you are getting the wrong type of data back.

Comment: I don't think your explanation is valid here.. I think apart from octet-stream type it also expects the text/plain content type for other generic purpose.

Comment: The default is `application/json` if you use `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`  you then added `application/octet-stream` but were receiving `text/plain` hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetwroking won't parse income data for you.

Use NSJSONSerialization's class method `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. If your data is valid, result will be NSDictionary with same structure as original JSON file

You should place it inside success block